# Allowing the browser to highlight a particular row in grid view which has paging

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a grid view which allows paging. I have 100 records for each page. Now the user wants a search text box and a button for search a particular record. On click of search they wanted to go to the page where they found the record and highlight that row in that page. How can I go to that page when I found that record?

Comment: What do you want to know, how to highlight that particular row or how to find the page-index of a specific record or how to go to that page? Currently your question is too broad and shows no own effort.

Comment: And you are doing it in?... WPF, WinForms, ASP.Net, AngularJS...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method and apply the datasource. Then use that datasource to find the correct page-index of the searched record. That shouldn't be too difficult. 
Once you have it you need to calculate the `PageIndex`.

Something like:

```
int pageIndex = selectedRecordIndex / gridView.PageSize;
gridView.PageIndex = pageIndex;
```

Then you just need to calculate the correct `SelectedIndex`. Try this:

```
gridView.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex % gridView.PageSize;
```